WebClient mock of doOnError onError method not invoked
Method(working in real-time, unit test failing):
@Override
    public <T> Flux<T> getAsyncCollection(ParameterizedTypeReference<T> type, String baseUrl, String endpointPath,
                                          Map<String, String> pathVariables, Map<String, String> queryParameters
            , int maxNumberOfRetries, long delay) {
        Flux<T> collectionResponse = null;

        try {
            WebClient webClient = webClientConfig.getWebClient();

            collectionResponse = webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(getURI(baseUrl, endpointPath, pathVariables, queryParameters))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(type)
                    .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(maxNumberOfRetries, Duration.ofMillis(delay)).
                            filter(this::isServerError)
                            .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> retrySignal.failure()))
                    .doOnError(ClientHttp4xxClient.class, this::throwHttpClientException);

        } catch (HttpClientException httpClientException) {
            throw httpClientException;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new HttpServerException(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, exception);
        }

        return collectionResponse;
    }

private boolean isServerError(Throwable throwable) {

        return !(ClientHttp4xxClient.class.isAssignableFrom(throwable.getClass()));
    }

private void throwHttpClientException(ClientHttp4xxClient clientHttp4xxClientException) {
...
}

Test code:
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class HttpWebClientTest {

@Mock
private WebClientConfig webClientConfig;
private WebClient webClient;
private HttpRestClient httpRestClient;
WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpec;
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec;
WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {

     webClient = mock(WebClient.class);

     when(webClientConfig.getWebClient()).thenReturn(webClient);
     httpRestClient = new HttpWebClient(webClientConfig);

     requestHeadersUriSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec.class);
        requestHeadersSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
        responseSpec = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);

     when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
    }

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getClientHttp4xxClientExceptions")
void asyncMethods_HttpClientException(ClientHttp4xxClient clientHttp4xxClient, Class expectedException) {

   setUpMocksForUriSpec();
   when(responseSpec.bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {})).thenReturn(Flux.error(clientHttp4xxClient));

   Assertions.assertThrows(expectedException, () -> httpRestClient.getAsyncCollection(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                                                                                           }, CustomerAgreementsMockData.CORE_CUAGR_BASE_URL, APIEndpoints.CORE_CUAGR_GET_CUSTOMER_AGREEMENTS,
                PATH_VARIABLES, QUERY_PARAMETERS, NO_OF_RETRIES, DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS));

}

private void setUpMocksForUriSpec() {
        when(requestHeadersUriSpec.uri(getURI(CustomerAgreementsMockData.CORE_CUAGR_BASE_URL, APIEndpoints.CORE_CUAGR_GET_CUSTOMER_AGREEMENTS, PATH_VARIABLES, QUERY_PARAMETERS))).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
    }

}

The unit test fails saying that nothing is thrown. I debugged, and found that neither isServerError() nor throwHttpClientException() are called. What am I missing?

The URI stub and other values seem okay:


Show setUpMocksForUriSpec()

@knittl Now I have added code for setUp() method, and also setUpMocksForUriSpec().

Does your stubbing call for requestHeadersUriSpec.uri match the actual invocation? Can you set a breakpoint to verify that the stubbed values are returned?

@knittl Added screenshot showing stubbed values, those look okay. The doOnError isn't invoked at all.

Where do you stub retryWhen? I don't see this method stubbed.

@knittl I haven't stubbed retryWhen. Is it required?

...bodyToFlux(type).retryWhen(...).doOnError(...) if you don't stub retryWhen, what do you think calling the method will return?
